# Device automatically unregisters from GCM with a null error

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am building an app with the `Google Cloud Messaging` librarys. The device (API 10) is giving problems although device with API 15 works fine.

The Problem with API 10,
In the first place, the device is able to register with GCM and able to generate a registration ID during the registration. However when a message is sent to the device from the server, the app automatically calls the `onUnregistered` method within the `GCMintent service class` and also give null value for the error. that is shown below

Below are my codes.

```
    // This is the GCMIntentService class

    public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
        private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";


        public GCMIntentService() {
            super("IntentService");
        }

        /**
         * Method called on device registered
         **/
        @Override
        protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);

        }
        /**
         * Method called on Receiving a new message
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Received message");

        }

        /**
         * Method called on device un registred
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered from the app");

        }


            /**
             * Method called on receiving a deleted message
             * */
            @Override
            protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");

            }

            /**
             * Method called on Error
             * */
            @Override
            public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
                //displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
                // log message
                Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);

                return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
            }


        }




    /**
     * The log cat summary when the message is sent to the app
     */

    10-07 13:24:20.484    9792-9792/com.ankoibia.maiddadfmd V/GCMBroadcastReceiver﹕ onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
    10-07 13:24:20.484    9792-9792/com.ankoibia.maiddadfmd V/GCMBroadcastReceiver﹕ GCM IntentService class: com.ankoibia.maiddadfmd.GCMIntentService
    10-07 13:24:20.515    9792-9792/com.ankoibia.maiddadfmd V/GCMBaseIntentService﹕ Acquiring wakelock
    10-07 13:24:20.546    9792-9792/com.ankoibia.maiddadfmd V/GCMBaseIntentService﹕ Intent service name: GCMIntentService-IntentService-1
    10-07 13:24:20.546    9792-9956/com.ankoibia.maiddadfmd E/GCMRegistrar﹕ internal error: retry receiver class not set yet
    10-07 13:24:20.546    9792-9956/com.ankoibia.maiddadfmd V/GCMRegistrar﹕ Registering receiver
    10-07 13:24:20.570    9792-9956/com.ankoibia.maiddadfmd D/GCMBaseIntentService﹕ handleRegistration: registrationId = null, error = null, unregistered = com.ankoibia.maiddadfmd
    10-07 13:24:20.570    9792-9956/com.ankoibia.maiddadfmd D/GCMRegistrar﹕ resetting backoff for com.ankoibia.maiddadfmd
    10-07 13:24:20.585    9792-9956/com.ankoibia.maiddadfmd V/GCMRegistrar﹕ Saving regId on app version 1
    10-07 13:24:20.585    9792-9956/com.ankoibia.maiddadfmd I/GCMIntentService﹕ Device unregistered from the app
    10-07 13:24:20.585    9792-9956/com.ankoibia.maiddadfmd V/GCMBaseIntentService﹕ Releasing wakelock
```

Please is there something I am suppose to do? I would be grateful, if some one could help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[GCMBaseIntentService](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/09/conference-data-sync-gcm-google-io.html) is deprecated, you should be using [GcmListenerService](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmListenerService) instead. GcmListenerService should work on API 10. Consult [this quickstart](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/MyGcmListenerService.java) to get an idea of using it.